# Referencing variables in nested modules in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cognito

I am working on a lambda authorizer for user pool authentication using terraform, I need to set the environment variables dynamically from `src>modules>application-services>modules>application-service>variables.tf` to `src>modules>lambda-auth>variables.tf`. I am not sure how to reference it I have declared them in the outputs.tf for `application-services>modules>application-service>variables.tf`. This is my file structure.

```
src
 ┣ modules
 ┃ ┣ application-services
 ┃ ┃ ┣ modules
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ application-service
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ api.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ outputs.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ providers.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ stage-variables.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ stages.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ variables.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┣ application-service.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┣ providers.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┗ variables.tf
 ┃ ┣ lambda-auth
 ┃ ┃ ┣ resource
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ lambda-authorizer.zip
 ┃ ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ auth.go
 ┃ ┃ ┣ lambda.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┣ providers.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┗ variables.tf
 ┣ application-services.tf
 ┣ main.tf
 ┣ outputs.tf
 ┣ providers.tf
 ┣ remote.tf
 ┗ variables.tf
 ┗ lambda-main.tf
```

this my src>modules>application>services>modules>application-service>outputs.tf file

```
output "user-pool-id" {
  value = var.service.app_name
}
```

this my src>modules>application>services>modules>application-service>variables.tf file

```
variable "service" {
  description = "The service which we want to deploy into the gateway"
  type = object({
    name           = string
    app_name       = string
    route          = string
    attributes     = map(string)
    user_pool_arns = list(string)
    environments = list(object({
      name      = string
      vpcLinkId = string
      domainId  = string
      uri       = string
    }))
  })
}
```

I want to grab the value of "app_name", and use it in `src>modules>lambda-auth>lambda.tf`, I want to use that "app_name" in place of "var.dev_appid", I have already taken care od the other aspect like creating the IAM roles and policies.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "authorizer_lambda_parser" {
  filename      = data.archive_file.lambda_resources_zip.output_path
  function_name = "lambda-authorizer"
  handler       = "auth.go"
  runtime       = "go1.x"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_authorizer_parser_role.arn

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_resources_zip.output_base64sha256
  environment {
    variables = {
      Dev_Region = var.dev_region
      Dev_AppID  = var.dev_appid
      Dev_Stage  = var.dev_stage
      Dev_UserPoolId = var.dev_userpoolid
      Dev_CognitoClients = var.dev_cognitoclient
      Prod_Region = var.prod_region
      Prod_AppId  = var.prod_appid
      Prod_Stage  = var.prod_stage
      Prod_UserPoolId = var.prod_userpoolid
      Prod_CognitoClients = var.prod_cognitoclient
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `src>modules>lambda-auth>variables.tf` file

```
variable "dev_region" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = "Region for Dev Environment"
}

variable "dev_appid" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " App ID for Dev Environment"
}
variable "dev_stage" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " Stage for Dev Environment"
}
variable "dev_userpoolid" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " User Pool ID for Dev Environment"
}
variable "dev_cognitoclient" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " Cognito Client ID for Dev Environment"
}
variable "prod_region" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = "Region for Prod Environment"
}
variable "prod_appid" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " App ID for Prod Environment"
}
variable "prod_stage" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " Stage for Prod Environment"
}
variable "prod_userpoolid" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " User Pool ID for Prod Environment"
}
variable "prod_cognitoclient" {
    default = ""
    type    = string
    description = " Cognito Client ID for Prod Environment"
}
```

This my lambda-main.tf file:

```
module "lambda-auth" {
  source = "lambda-auth"

  prod_userpoolid = module.application-services.user-pool-id
}
```

This is my `src>application-serivces.tf` file:
# We retrieve the necessary information for each of the services including: user_pool_arns, vpcLinkId, domainId
locals {
app_service_input = { for app_file, application in local.app_object_list : application.name => flatten([
for service in application.services : [merge(service,
{
app_name       = application.name
user_pool_arns = [for user_pool in application.user_pools : module.iam-pools[user_pool].results.pool.arn]
environments = [for environment in service.environments :
{
name      = environment.name
vpcLinkId = module.gateway-link[environment.link].results.vpcLinkId
domainId  = module.gateway-domain[app_file].results.domain[application.domains.service][environment.name]
uri       = environment.uri
}] })]
]) }
}

```
module "application-services" {
  source = "./modules/application-services"

  providers = {
    aws.gateway = aws.networking
  }

  for_each = local.app_service_input

  application_services = each.value
}
```

I am not sure how to reference from one module to the other, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference values directly from one module to another at all. The level where the `module` is declared is the only level that has access to the module's outputs. To pass those values to other levels you have to declare the value as an output of the `application-services` module also, which will make it available in `main`. Then declare an input variable for the `lambda` module, and have `main` pass the value into the `lambda` module.

---

`application-services/outputs.tf`

```
output "user-pool-id" {
  value = module.application-service.user-pool-id
}
```

`main.tf`

```
module "lambda-auth" {
  source = "lambda-auth"

  prod_userpoolid = module.application-services.user-pool-id
}
```

Comment: I have declared the variable in outputs.tf which theoretically means I should be able to use it in my lambda.tf, but the last part where you said I need to 'declare an input variable for lambda module, and have main pass the value into lambda module'. How do I do that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No, you declared it in outputs.tf of `application-service` which means it is available inside `application-services` currently, and nowhere else. You are missing the part where the submodule's outputs are only available to the calling module. You first need to add an outputs.tf to `application-services` and output the value again from there, which will make it available in `main`. Then you need to pass that as an input to `lambda` just like you are already passing other inputs to `lambda`.

Comment: @figuring see the code example I added to my answer

Comment: I am sorry this is a beginner question again but I have created the outputs.tf file under 'application-services', but I am not sure how to declare it, should it be the same code again as in the 'application-service' outputs.tf.  also does it affect the code that the variable to be declared in lambda.tf is a map of variables.

Comment: @figuring See my updated answer please, I gave you the exact code you need to add to that outputs.tf file.

Comment: "also does it affect the code that the variable to be declared in lambda.tf is a map of variables" there are no variables of type `map` in the `lambda-auth/variables.tf` file you included in your question, just lots of individual variables of type `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think your code will be able to declare the variables in main.tf but for lambda.tf to call it shouldn't we have to make changes in 'variables.tf' of 'lambda-auth', since we are calling that specific variables  file.

Comment: I have no idea what your last question means. You have variables declared in your `lambda-auth` module. If `main` is declaring a `module "lambda-auth"` then it needs to pass values for all those variables, like I show it passing a value for `prod_userpoolid` in my answer. If you need more specific help then you probably need to include more of your Terraform code, like all your `module` declarations, in your question.

Comment: This is most of the code , I am just confused as to how 'lambda.tf' will take 'user-pool-id' as a var.dev_userpoolid if not being specified in varibles.tf .

Comment: variables.tf specifies the input values that `main` needs to set when it creates an instance of `lambda-auth` module. variables.tf does not pull values out of other modules, it simply declares what the modules inputs need to be, it is up to the parent module to set the input values. Like I keep saying, if you want the exact code, then show me your `module` declarations.

Comment: I have updates my question I am declaring the module inside lambda-main.tf since we are using main.tf file only for terraform block. Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Where are you declaring the other modules? Show them all please. Also, did the code I gave you not work somehow?

Comment: Also, when I say `main` I'm talking about every file in the same `/src` folder, not just `main.tf`. With Terraform, every file in the same folder is at the same "level" and has access to the same values.

Comment: No, I am actually getting an error 
on module/application-services/modules/application-service/outputs.tf line 2, in output "user-pool-id":
2: value = module.application-services.user-pool-id
No module call named "application-service" is declared in module.application-services.module.application-services.

Comment: You were supposed to put that output in `application-services/outputs.tf` which is a new file you need to create. See the filename I specified in my answer.

Comment: This is the error I seem to be getting after your suggested changes, 
 
 on lambda-main.tf line 4, in module "lambda-auth":
  4:   prod_userpoolid             = module.application-services.user-pool-id

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "prod_userpoolid" defined at
/modules/lambda-auth/variables.tf:42,1-27: string required.

Comment: Is `module.application-services.user-pool-id` not a string?

Comment: it is a list of strings

Comment: Then you'll have to pull out the correct item from the list...